# Объявлять переменную в среде и передавать ее как переменную

Tags: javascript, canvas

Хочу, чтобы не нужно было объявлять переменную, а она объявлялась в среде и передавать ее как переменную.

Вот такой код есть:

```
function createNewPath(namePath,[...arr],color) {
  let namePath = new Path2D()
  namePath.rect(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])
  namePath.closePath()
  ctx.fillStyle = `${color}`;
  ctx.fill(namePath)
  ctx.stroke(namePath)
}

    let contentPath = new Path2D();
    createNewPath(contentPath,[0, height - height / 3, width, height - height / 2],"rgba(43, 41, 41, 1)")
    let redLine = new Path2D();
    createNewPath(redLine,[0, height - height / 3, width, 4],"rgb(255, 0, 0)")
```

Comment: А что значит "объявлялась в среде"? А про какую именно переменную речь?

Comment: Внутри функции createNewPath а переменная namePath

Comment: Не ясно что ты хочешь. Если просто передавать переменную ты её уже передаёшь. А чтобы не было никаких ошибок или перетираний, нужно просто удалить строку `let namePath = new Path2D()`, тогда переменная, которая объявлена вне функции и переданная внутрь - будет функцией и использоваться